# Repository login performance using Apache Jackrabbit

Tags: jackrabbit

```
Session session = repository.login(new SimpleCredentials("username", "password".toCharArray()));
```

I am using Apache Jackrabbit in embdeed mode.  using the 'default' out of the box set up, it takes about 10 seconds just to login to a new repository.  is there a way to speed this up? Perhaps settings in the registory.xml i need to modify to hopefully get it down to 1 second or less time it take to login.

Thanks.

Comment: Needs more details. Version? Size? Persistence? And are you sure that it's not the construction of the Repository object?

Comment: Version 2.16.  im certain it was repository.login.  getting the initial repository was quick....also, performance dropped after large number of documents, so going with another solution.

Comment: Is by any chance the large number of documents in a single folder?

Comment: it was one document.